# java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died

Tags: android

I got the following exception from crashlytics on a API Level 22 YU5510 device. The frequency of occurring this exception is not that higher. Is it any hardware related issue or device specific issue?

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receivercom.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2649)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800 (ActivityThread.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1398)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5292)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:904)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:699)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.resolveService (ApplicationPackageManager.java:638)
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zze ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zzh ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zzb ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.onReceive ()
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2642)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800 (ActivityThread.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1398)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5292)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:904)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:699)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException: 
android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Binder.java)
android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:496)
android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.resolveService (IPackageManager.java:2669)
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.resolveService (ApplicationPackageManager.java:632)
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zze ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zzh ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zzb ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.onReceive ()
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2642)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800 (ActivityThread.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1398)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5292)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:904)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sss.lll" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.sss.lll.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sss.lll.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/m_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="MyApp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ListActivity"
            android:launchMode= "singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.DetailActivity"
            android:launchMode= "singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.ListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.WebviewActivity"
            android:launchMode= "singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.ListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ViewPagerImageActivity"
            android:launchMode= "singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.DetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LikeActivity"
            android:launchMode= "singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.ListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           ></activity>


        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="1234567899" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show me your manifest file

Comment: @JdPrajapati see, i've posted it

Answer (score 0):

Add this receiver and check it.

```
Internal receiver for FirebaseInstanceId used to start services securely. This receiver is automatically added to your application's manifest file via manifest merge. If necessary it can be manually declared via:

 <receiver
     android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
     android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: i got this error in crashlytics. so need time to check